# Encryption when pdf is attached to Outlook Mail

Tags: vba, pdf, encryption, outlook

I want to encrypt whenever an attachment with PDF extension is added to mail with Outlook vba.

Is there a way to write such a macro?

Thanky you?

Comment: Password will be transmitted via different channels

Comment: Encryption is required by law. My goal is to encrypt the pdf attachment that I add when I open a new e-mail to send it to the recipient, with the password I set.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [MailItem.AttachmentAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.attachmentadd) event which is fired when an attachment has been added to an Outlook item. So, you could check the attached file - the `Attachment` that was added to the item is passed as a parameter and encrypt it if required. For example:

```
Public WithEvents newItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 
Private Sub newItem_AttachmentAdd(ByVal newAttachment As Attachment)
 If newAttachment.Type = olByValue Then 
   newItem.Save 
   If newItem.Size > 500000 Then 
     MsgBox "Warning: Item size is now " & newItem.Size & " bytes." 
   End If 
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Public Sub TestAttachAdd() 
 Dim atts As Outlook.Attachments 
 Dim newAttachment As Outlook.Attachment 
 
 Set newItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 newItem.Subject = "Test attachment" 
 Set atts = newItem.Attachments 
 Set newAttachment = atts.Add("C:\Test.txt", olByValue) 
End Sub
```

Note, you can find the cached file on disk. You can find the actual path in the windows registry:

[image: Outlook cached folder path in Windows registry]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but how can I encrypt the pdf?

Comment: It depends on the algorithm chosen. You deal with a file which can be processed in any way you need.